# How can I underline mathematics using a harpoon of variable size?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, vertical-alignment, text-decorations, stacking-symbols

I am a new user of LaTeX. I want to underline the answers to mathematics problems using a `\rightharpoondown` symbol. If possible, I would like a `\rightharpoondown` of variable size, as in the image below. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You mention \rightharpoondown but the link to your example doesn't use it; it circles the answer. Is a circled answer what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry the insufficient my question. I mentioned it follow the two examples.

$\overset{5 Volts}{\rightharpoondown}$

$\underset{\rightharpoondown}{4 Volts}$

But \rightharpoondown will be variable.

Comment: Now that I know you are talking about \rightharpoondown, please explain what is your problem with it, what you actually want to attain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is are three macros that (1) underline with a hook, (2) circle an answer (with an ellipse) and (3) that place two diagonal lines in the lower right corner. Note that I used the `siunitx` package to write the answer; this package is made to correctly write the units of a value.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\answer}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=(answer.base)]{
\node[inner sep=3pt] (answer) {#1};
\draw[line cap=round] (answer.south west) -- (answer.south east)  -- ++(-0.1,-0.1); 
}} 

\newcommand{\answercircled}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=(answer.base)]{
\node[ellipse,draw,inner sep=3pt] (answer) {#1};
}} 

    \newcommand{\answerside}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=(answer.base)]{
\node[inner sep=3pt] (answer) {#1};
\draw[double, double distance=2pt] ($(answer.south east) + (45:0.2)$) -- ($(answer.south east) - (45:0.2)$);
}} 

\begin{document}
$x = \answer{\SI{5}{Volts}} = \answercircled{\SI{5}{Volts}}= \answerside{\SI{5}{Volts}}$

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After that teaching my example, again thank you Frédéric.

```
 \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{color}

 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

 \newcommand{\answer}[1]{
 \tikz[baseline=(answer.base)]{
 \node[inner sep=3pt] (answer) {#1};
 \color{red}
 \draw[line width=1pt,color=red][line cap=round] {[rounded corners](answer.south west) -- (answer.south east) } -- ++(-0.5,-0.5);
 }} 

 \begin{document}

 $x = \answer{\SI{5.977}{Volts}}$

 \end{document}
```

The result is

[image]